# Null result in LINQ vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq, null, sequence

Hi people :) I'm having trouble with a null result, when I compare the query it said I cant it give the following error "sequence contains no elements"

```
Dim existe = (
    From   p In abc.Ventadetalles 
    Where  p.idarticulo = txtArticulo.Text 
    And    p.idventa = IdventaTextBox.Text 
    Select p).Single
```

here is the code

Comment: You obviously did not even Google for the answer.

Comment: well I Google it but not even what they said fix the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will work:

```
Dim existe = (
    From   p In abc.Ventadetalles 
    Where  p.idarticulo = txtArticulo.Text 
    And    p.idventa = IdventaTextBox.Text 
    Select p).SingleOrDefault()

If existe Is Not Nothing Then
    '' here you can use existe
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using SingleOrDefault. This should work.

Alternatively you could use Any() since it looks like you are trying to test for existence.

Answer (score 2):

The error is correct: the sequence has no elements! You are using `Single()`, so empty sequences produce an error. If you'd like to instead return the default value, then use `SingleOrDefault()`.

If you expect there to actually be elements in the sequence, then double-check your conditions and source data again.

Comment: mmm ok ok i try it and it works ... but still in the next line I have an if statement and it said is null... PS: how do I change the null result into a 0 thnx for reply